# How asymmetric is this matrix

Tags: matrices, symmetry

I see the matrix is clearly asymmetrical. The lower triangle has significantly higher values than the upper triangle. But I want to get some kind of measure, indicator for this. Is there an established way to define how assymetrical a matrix is?
Matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    6 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    4 & 8 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thanks

Comment: one s, two m, asymmetric

Comment: Some answers can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-determine-how-symmetric-a-matrix-is), this is an old question. For example, take the symmetric part $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$.

Comment: Thanks, is this answer just a guess or established way to go? "define the symmetric part As = (A+A')/2 and the anti-symmetric part Aa = (A-A')/2 -- together this makes A=As+Aa -- and define ||Aa|| / ||As|| as a measure of symmetry."

Comment: Why do you need such measure? For different applications there might be quite different established ways.

Comment: @uranix for the academic paper and to be sure that my matrix after some operation becomes more assymetrical than before. Plus I assume the measure should point the direction (like correlation) with negative values showing lower triangle dominates and poistive when upper domiantes...